# CSV and Database

Tags: mysql, csv

Suppose there are changes in the .CSV file which I've used to enter data in the database, how can I reflect those changes in the same database, say using MySQL Workbench or MySQL command line?

Comment: Look into `REPLACE INTO`. You could also wipe the table and re-import it.

Comment: What do you mean by changes - changes in structure or changes in content.

Comment: could you please elaborate @BarryCarter?

Comment: yeah, I meant changes in content of the .CSV file! @P.Salmon